How do i copy specific rows using VBA?
I have to copy a highlighted column from one worksheet to another. Marks for certain criteria are highlighted and I want to copy them to the row under the column of the same group number in another worksheet.
Private Sub CopyHighlightedMarksToMarksBreakdown()
    Const marksColumn As Long = 4 ' Column D in Marks Breakdown
    Const startRow As Long = 5 ' Starting row in Marks Breakdown
    Dim marksBreakdownWs As Worksheet
    Dim feedbackWs As Worksheet
    Dim groupNumber As String
    Dim groupColumn As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set marksBreakdownWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Marks Breakdown")
    Set feedbackWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feedback Comments")

    ' Get the group number from G2 in Feedback Comments sheet
    groupNumber = feedbackWs.Cells(2, 7).Value ' Cell G2

    ' Find the column number in Marks Breakdown sheet that matches the group number
    groupColumn = 0
    For i = 1 To marksBreakdownWs.Cells(2, marksBreakdownWs.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If marksBreakdownWs.Cells(2, i).Value = groupNumber Then
            groupColumn = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If groupColumn = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Group number not found in Marks Breakdown sheet", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Clear existing marks in Marks Breakdown starting from row 5
    For j = startRow To marksBreakdownWs.Rows.Count
        If Not marksBreakdownWs.Cells(j, groupColumn).MergeCells Then
            marksBreakdownWs.Cells(j, groupColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next j

    j = startRow ' Initialize row counter for Marks Breakdown

    ' Loop through all rows in Feedback Comments to find highlighted marks
    For i = 1 To feedbackWs.Cells(feedbackWs.Rows.Count, marksColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        If feedbackWs.Cells(i, marksColumn).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 218, 185) Then
            ' Copy the highlighted mark to the next available row in the corresponding group column
            marksBreakdownWs.Cells(j, groupColumn).Value = feedbackWs.Cells(i, marksColumn).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

This is the code i tried but it did not work

Make sure the Developer tab is showing in Excel, click the Record Macro button, Copy a Row, Paste it as per your process, Stop the Macro and in VBA check the newly created Module with the Copy/Paste code. This is a great way to learn weird features of VBA and it looks like you've got VBA coding/syntax under control.

What is the exact description of did not work?
